# MySQL Query using foreign key relationship

Tags: mysql

I am learning MySQL and I am trying to make simple arithmetic in the query,
I am trying to write a command that would determine the number of `Instructors` in each Faculty in the university
Can anyone help me in this? Thank you!

Here below are my two tables:

```
    ________________________________________________________
    |    Department       |    Faculty         |  Building  |      
    --------------------------------------------------------        
    |    Humanities       |  Arts and Sciences |  Chardon   |
    |     English         |  Arts and Sciences |  Chardon   |
    |   Mathematics       |  Arts and Sciences |  Monzon    |
    | General Engineering |    Engineering     |  Stefani   |
    |     Agronomy        |    Agriculture     |  Pinero    |

     _________________________________________________________________________
    |  Professor  |      Department        |      Rank           |  Salary    |
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |  Joe Blow   |         Biology        |     Professor       | $73,500.00 |
    |  Sam Snow   |       Mathematics      |     Instructor      | $45,700.00 |   
    | George Grow | Electrical Engineering | Associate Professor | $69,250.00 |
    | Hiram Lowe  |         English        | Assistant Professor | $63,750.00 |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something close to this:

```
select department.faculty, count(professor.professor) as instructors from department join professor on department.department = professor.department group by department.faculty
```

Basically you do a join to "merge" the two tables, then group results by faculty, and count professors for each faculty.